# tkinter notebook y layout manager

Tags: tkinter

Repasando distintos ejemplos de implementación de notebook, me ha llamado la atención que en este ejemplo:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText


def demo():
       root = tk.Tk()
       root.title("ttk.Notebook")

       nb = ttk.Notebook(root)

       # adding Frames as pages for the ttk.Notebook 
       # first page, which would get widgets gridded into it
       page1 = ttk.Frame(nb)

       # second page
       page2 = ttk.Frame(nb)
       text = ScrolledText(page2)
       text.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

       nb.add(page1, text='One')
       nb.add(page2, text='Two')

       nb.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

       root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
       demo()
```

los frames page1 y page2 no esten **"explicitamente"** gestionados por un layout manager, en este caso pack() y si embargo funcionen correctamente. Este ejemplo, creo está extraido de una documentación oficial.

En toda la documentación que leo, se recalca que si los widgets no se gestionan con un layout manager, no se hacen visibiles.

Si quisiera gestionar page1 y page2 con grid(), ¿Como debería indicar las columnas para cada uno de ellos?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes gestionar el contenido de cada Frame con el administrador de geometría que quieras. Una cosa es lo que posicionas dentro del widget `raiz` de cada pestaña (en el ejemplo un Frame, que usa `pack` para posicionar sus hijos) y otra cómo se posiciona el propio widget raíz (el Frame) en el panel del NoteBook.

Internamente **el widget raíz de cada pestaña se posiciona implícitamente al llamar al método `add` y se posiciona en el panel del NoteBook como si se usara `grid`**. Hay que tener en cuenta que  solo podemos tener un widget raíz por cada pestaña, por lo tanto un grid con una única fila y columna.

En tu ejemplo el "árbol genealógico" de la app es:

```
tk.Tk (root)
 |
 |__ ttk.NoteBook (posicionado en root con pack)
      |
      |__ ttk.Frame (widget raiz de tab 1, posicionado con grid implícitamente)
      |
      |__ ttk.Frame (widget raiz de tab 2, posicionado con grid implícitamente)
           |
           |__ ScrolledText (posicionado con pack)
```

De hecho, `add` tiene un argumento `sticky` que actúa idénticamente a como lo hace el argumento de `grid`:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText


def demo():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("ttk.Notebook")

    nb = ttk.Notebook(root)

    s = ttk.Style()
    s.configure('page1.TFrame', background='red')
    page1 = ttk.Frame(nb,  style="page1.TFrame")
    tk.Label(page1, text="Hola StackOverFlow").grid(row=0,  column=0)
    tk.Label(page1, text="Hola Chemag").grid(row=1,  column=0)

    nb.add(page1, text='One', sticky="NS")
    nb.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
nb.add(page1, text='One', sticky="E")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
nb.add(page1, text='One', sticky="NSEW")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al igual que cuando se usa explícitamente `grid`, `sticky` permite indicar hacia dónde se "debe de tirar" del widget, permitiendo definir que debe pasar con el espacio sobrante del panel, si una vez que el widget raíz se ha expandido para contener sus hijos, sobra espacio en el panel del NoteBook.

No podemos modificar ésto, el módulo `ttk` en éste caso se limita a actuar de wrapper sobre tcl/tk usando `tkinter.call` para llamar al comando `add` de `ttk::notebook`.

Como comentaba, `add` posiciona de forma implícita el widget raíz para esa pestaña, generalmente es un `Frame`, pero puede ser cualquier widget:

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk


def demo():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("ttk.Notebook")
    root.geometry("450x200")

    nb = ttk.Notebook(root)

    tk.Label(nb,  text="Hola StackOverFlow")

    nb.add(page1, text='One', sticky="NSEW")
    nb.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    demo()
```

Ahora bien, podemos posicionar dentro del widget raíz (si lo permite, por eso se usa comúnmente un `Frame`) los widgets que queramos y usar el administrador de geometría que queramos, en mi ejemplo uso `grid`:

```
page1 = ttk.Frame(nb,  style="page1.TFrame") # <<< Widget raiz de la pestaña
tk.Label(page1, text="Hola StackOverFlow").grid(row=0,  column=0) # <<< Widget hijo del widget raiz
#                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
tk.Label(page1, text="Hola Chemag").grid(row=1,  column=0)
#                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Pero puedes usar el que quieras:

```
tk.Label(page1, text="Hola StackOverFlow").pack()
tk.Label(page1, text="Hola Chemag").pack()
```

---

```
tk.Label(page1, text="Hola StackOverFlow").place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25)
tk.Label(page1, text="Hola Chemag").place(relx=0.5,  rely=0.75)
```

Lo que no puedes definir es cómo se posiciona el widget raíz, en éste caso nuestro frame en el panel, más allá de gestionar `sticky`. Ésto no entraña ninguna limitación, dado que posicionando un `Frame` como raíz podemos colocar y posicionar los widgets hijos que queramos con el administrador de geometría que queramos y los anidamientos que queramos en la pestaña.

Comment: Perfecto. Entendido. **add** actua como un **grid** parcial. Al ver que faltaba el layout manager explicitamente, he sentido como si de derrumbara, de repente, toda mi torre de conocimiento. :-). Estaba claro que no podía ser así.

Comment: Yo me siento mas cómodo empleando grid() que pack(). Siento que puedo controlar mas lo que deseo hacer, por eso intento cambiar los pack()'s por grid()'s, y me sirve de práctica. El problema me surgió, que con los cambios que hice la ScrolledText, no se me expandía al cambiar el tamaño, a pesar del sticky. Ya lo he resuelto con **weight = 1** en columconfigure y el rowconfigure de page2